# Integrate aerospike client in erlang environment as global module

Tags: erlang, aerospike

I want to integrate the aerospike erlang client to the erlang environment as a global module in Fedora 21.
I achieve to make the client nif and module but I have to always copy the files in every project. 
Now I want to use the aerospike module like the erlang or os modules. 
How can I make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when experimenting with the Aerospike binding. The problem is that the `.so` file is assumed to be in the current working directory.  I made a small change to `aerospike.erl` so it's located correctly independent of the path.

Replace

```
ok = erlang:load_nif("./aerospike_nif", 0).
```

in `init()`

with

```
  EbinDir = filename:dirname(code:which(?MODULE)),
  SoFile  = filename:join(EbinDir,"aerospike_nif"),
  erlang:load_nif(SoFile, 0).
```

When starting `erl`, add the path to the directory containing the Aerospike beam files and `.so`: `erl -pa path_to_aerospike/erlang/`

Comment: I can work with that, thank you.
what means this sentence ? `code:which(?MODULE)`

Comment: `?MODULE` is a macro that evaluates to the name of the current module, `aerospike` in this case.  `code:which/1` returns the absolute path to the file that contains the module definition.